# Draw lines in Crystal via Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal report in Visual Studio Community 2015. I want to draw tables from the designer and put fields in the cells. But I couldn't find how to draw table or event boxes or lines? Attached image is the snapshot from visual studio. Anyone can help? Many thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer myself. I can just right-click and select 'insert'...thanks!

Comment: you went to the extent of creating a post.. when you could have just played within the software. It was that easy. I guess thats the reliance on internet and google thats doing this.